# Get notified in Application.EnableEvents = False

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to be notified by a message box or something similar if `Application.EnableEvents = False`

I am using this `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent loops and in error handlers.  On occasions, it isn't being set to true on exiting the sub.  I need to resolve this but would like a notification if it occurs.

By its very nature, I cant call a message box sub if `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: Events may remain disabled if the code is imprecise. The cure for faulty code isn't more code but less, so as to eliminate the imprecision. The other reason is a crash. You may consider the crash itself notification of events having been disabled.

Comment: Use a UDF which returns the value of `EnableEvents` and enter the formula on your most-important worksheets. Format the cell using conditional formatting to highlight when the value is False.

Comment: @TimWilliams  I like this idea but I'm not sure how to execute it.  Would you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

```vb
Function EventsOn()
    Application.Volatile
    EventsOn = Application.EnableEvents
End Function
```

so if you enter:

```
=EventsOn()
```

in a cell and conditionally format it to red fill when the value is FALSE, you'll get an indicator that events are off.

Note this does rely on the formula being refreshed by a calculation.